# Is atheism religion with all attributes?

Tags: ethics, scientific-method, atheism, materialism, existence-of-god

To people who are believers, that science proved that God doesn’t exists, I want to remind that science tell that consciousness doesn’t exist too, however obviously consciousness exists.

I guess similar questions were asked before, however in this question I want to make an emphasis on Karl Popper’s falsifiability criteria, Chinese Room experiment and concept of Philosophical Zombies.

If moderator will take any action to interfere free discussion, I will consider an answer to my question is “yes”, and more than that atheism is wicked theology.

Comment: Where exactly does science prove that consciousness doesn’t exist? The “Chinese room” argument is nonsense. It basically says that I can’t have consciousness because my individual brain cells don’t.

Comment: BTW I am an evil atheist who downvoted you :-) Because of the massive fallacy in your last sentence.

Comment: @gnasher729 Ditto!

Comment: @gnasher729 regarding your first comment, I’ve already answered in question body, please read carefully. Regarding second comment thank you for your honesty. How many people killed due to Nietzsche’s idea - more than you can think.

Comment: @NotThatGuy it is perfectly binary question- that has answer True or False.

Comment: If you believe Atheism is an evil theology, take it up with your God. With a wave if his great hand, all atheists would be eliminated. Problem solved and proof that free-will is fantasy.

Comment: The title of this post is technically a question, but that doesn't seem to have much to do with what you've written in the body of the post. It seems like you're just trying to push a personal philosophy, rather than wanting to know the answer to a question, and the former is [not appropriate as a question here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Also, [we already have a question on [whether atheism is a religion](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/16016/could-secularism-or-atheism-or-materialism-be-considered-a-religion).

Comment: @NotThatGuy regarding your last comment, it is well explained in body of question - no need to repeat it again.

Comment: @DmytroBrazhnyk no, you are no man to condition others to answer ‘true’ or ‘false’

Comment: @tac please, give your extended answer then, beyond “true” or “false”, oh wait, you can’t anymore, how pity it is, because this is forbidden conversation by our fellow atheists. Their belief that God is dead is holy, of course there is a reason, however God is dead and no-one will tell them anymore to forgive their enemies, and they will form a coalition and will harass with any power they have, who tells something different to their beliefs. So I guess I’ve proved my point. Marking conversations about theology subject as off-topic in philosophy group is very questionable reason.

Comment: @DmytroBrazhnyk ‘God is dead’ is a sentence that must be understood metaphorically. People who said that are mostly nietzscheans and hence they aren't atheists.

Comment: @DmytroBrazhnyk The simple answer is that Atheism is clearly a religion to some.  Such atheists evangelize and attack other belief systems as being not as good as theirs.  I often agree with much of what they say, but they strike me as fundamentally inconsistent in promoting  the perceived goodness of their beliefs which they take on faith, at least in part.

Answer (score 1):

> atheism is wicked theology

Atheism (the lack of a belief in a god) is not a theology.

I don't think science has proven that god doesn't exist. (I'm not even sure if science *could* prove that.) I do think, though, that theists (those who believe a god or gods exist) haven't made a strong enough demonstration that the god/gods exist. I'll withhold my belief until the demonstration is made.

Comment: @DmytroBrazhnyk we don't need any kind of demostration in the cartesian sense in order to have an apodictic certanity that something is

Comment: I like your rational answer, you gave me hope, to believe that atheism is not a religion yet, but your alone in that, majority of people with their actions demonstrated that atheists is another form of belief that needs to be protected with as any other religion does…

Comment: Reasons for closing questions here are listed in the [help center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), they are topic-neutral. This one was closed because it is a pseudo-question that promotes a foregone conclusion rather than asks something. It makes no difference whether the topic is theism, atheism, solipsism, nihilism, determinism, feminism, anti-natalism, etc., analogous post would have been closed. This is not a blog or discussion forum for debates. But there are threads here on all of the above when the questions are genuine.

Comment: @Conifold please, don’t excuse

Comment: Actually flat earth believers they have “lack of beliefs into spherical Earth” even that evidence was presented to them, does lack of belief makes anyone closer to Truth, comparing to that one who believes - the short answer is no. Human soul is great evidence of supernatural mystical non-materialistic beginning of the universe. I like your argumentation, but is not enough, to say that atheism is not another form of theological belief.